# css html footer

Tags: html, css, footer

I am re-writing this question to better convey the problem:

I have 3 output mechanisms:

1. Screen
2. PDF
3. Print

PDF's are generated using the same media type as screen.

On screen: I just want the footer to appear below the content ... Simple... easy!

PDF: I want the footer to display at the bottom of the last page of the content

Print: As above, I want the footer to display at the bottom of the last page of the content

The problem is: If I set absolute positioning for media type=print there are two problems:

1. This has no effect of the PDF display
2. If the content spans over multiple pages, the content prints under the footer which is fixed at the bottom of the first page.

If on screen - I need footer to display at the bottom of an imaginary page so that when the pdf is generated, it appears at the bottom of the last page of content

If on print - I need footer to display at the bottom of the last page of content

Comment: What is the footer? Is it a div? If so, and it's already at the end of the document (source-wise), it should already appear at the bottom. Ignoring the absolute positioning (which won't work if the page size isn't fixed), what, specifically is going wrong?

Comment: Yes, absolute position for the footer is not a good solution.

Comment: take a look at @gutch's answer.  It shows you how to have one layout for PRINT and one for normal.

Comment: I already have one for print and one for normal.

Comment: How, exactly are you generating the PDF?  Also, why are you using absolute positioning if you just want the footer below the content?

Comment: Chris:
1. Generating PDF using PDFCrowd
2. i only want the footer below the content on screen - there are 2 other output mediums where i do NOT want the footer just below the content!

Answer (score 2):

You can define 2 stylesheets for the page; 1 for "screen" and 1 for "print".  Link to them this way:

```
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen">
<LINK rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="print.css" media="print">
```

This way you have total separation of how each device should render your page.

Comment: How are you generating a PDF from an HTML page?  Are you using some sort of component?  You could always have a "print friendly" button on your website that opens a new window.  It's kind of boring, but would do the trick for sure.

Comment: PDFCrowd to generate PDF using HTML
I can print "friendly" without a problem
The issue is with the footer positioning.

Comment: I think you could do this by declaring your footer in a <div> immediately before the closing </body> tag.  For the "screen" layout, use absolute positioning.  For "print" layout, use the default positioning which will display the footer at the bottom of the page naturally.  Lastly, I have never used PDFCrowd before, but it looks like there is a parameter 'use_print_media' (from http://pdfcrowd.com/doc/api/) that can be set that tells it which stylesheet to use.

Comment: Ok Dana - good find... That definitely sorts out point 1 in my question... Thanks!!!
Point 2 is still an issue though if the content spans over more than one page (absolute positioning positions the footer at the bottom of the first page...)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely check out http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/. It's an excellent, modern "sticky footer" solution. At a minimum, it should help lead you in the right direction.

Comment: There were no answers when I started typing/reviewing the technique. Didn't mean to step on any toes. Anyone who likes that link, please credit rockinthesixstring

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by having a separate CSS stylesheet for printed documents. CSS Media Types allow you specify separate rules for printed documents (and many other representations).

If this is the only style that needs special handling then you can put the print style in your existing stylesheet like this:

```
#footer { position: static; }

@media print {
    #footer { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
}
```

If you have a lot of print-specific rules, put them in a separate stylesheet and include both stylesheets in your HTML like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="printonly.css">
```

When displayed on the screen only the *all.css* stylesheet will be used; when printed both the *all.css* and the *printonly.css* stylesheet will be used — so you don't need to duplicate your styles in both files, just add printer-specific ones to *printonly.css*.

**Useful reference:**

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/media.html

Comment: I don't think he meant "print" as in @media print, but rather "display" - though I could be wrong.

Comment: oops.. looks like you're right after all.  The OP has edited his question and it refers to `@media print`

Comment: I can separate the two (media & print) however I cannot get either of them to print (display) how I want...
The problem is not separating media types - it is trying to get the media types to do what I need...

Comment: Actually I think I did get `@media print` and `@media display` mixed up in my answer above... but it seems the OP has that part under control, the problem is with the styles themselves.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think what you might be looking for is the [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)</strike>

Ultimately your footer needs to be outside of your wrapper

Page

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
/*  
Sticky Footer Solution
by Steve Hatcher 
http://stever.ca
http://www.cssstickyfooter.com
*/

* {margin:0;padding:0;} 

/* must declare 0 margins on everything, also for main layout components use padding, not 
vertical margins (top and bottom) to add spacing, else those margins get added to total height 
and your footer gets pushed down a bit more, creating vertical scroll bars in the browser */

html, body {height: 100%;}

#wrap {min-height: 100%;}

#main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {/* thanks to Maleika (Kohoutec)*/
content:"";
height:100%;
float:left;
width:0;
margin-top:-32767px;/* thank you Erik J - negate effect of float*/
}



/* IMPORTANT

You also need to include this conditional style in the <head> of your HTML file to feed this style to IE 6 and lower and 8 and higher.

<!--[if !IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrap {display:table;height:100%}
    </style>
<![endif]-->

*/
```

*Taken directly from the cssstickyfooter website.*

I posted my answer before the OP edited his answer to explain that he was looking for print.

Comment: to the downvoter - my answer was posted prior to the OP editing his original question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a single container css class.
2. Add the footer to the end after header & body containers.
3. Set the container height to 100%  & the footer class will appear at the bottom.